# How to add a user-agent style sheet to firefox browser?

Tags: firefox, user-agent, scrollbar

I am trying to increase the width of scrollbar in firefox and I found out that it can be done by adding a user-agent style sheet. It's not possible with userChrome.css or userContent.css

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that things like that may be determined by the theme. Take a look at the xpi files in the extensions subfolder.

Comment: @Mr Lister  can we add an extra user-agent style sheet to firefox. If you know the process, can you help me

Comment: Like I said, I'm not sure. I've never designed themes. But there is a possibility that the css in the theme will override your userChrome.css, especially when it contains `!important`. So you should have a look at those. Other than that, I won't be able to help you, because I'm no more an expert at themes than you are. Sorry.